# C# RestSharp get request failed

Tags: python, c#, timeout, restsharp

I'm trying to send GET request using C# RestSharp as follows.

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
var client = new RestClient("https://www.futureelectronics.cn/p/2052120");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

this code not working with timeout.

but python same code work well.

```
import requests

url = "https://www.futureelectronics.cn/p/2052120"

payload={}
headers = {}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

What is the cause of this error?
thank you.

Comment: IS there any exception?

Comment: That suggests to me that your URL is incorrect, or is being blocked.  Are you running the C# code from the same PC as the Python code? What happens if you don't set Tls12? What happens if you try cURL from the command line?

Comment: yes. there is no exception

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying it in a try catch block and seeing if an error is produced in that can shed some light on the reason.
And just in case your target refuses to use Tls12 I would also suggest swapping:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

for:

ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

One other thing, i have found adding:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);

has also helped me track down issues.

so:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AcceptAllCertifications);
var client = new
RestClient("https://www.futureelectronics.cn/p/2052120");
client.Timeout = -1;
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
try
{
    IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Caught exception : " + ex.message)
}
Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

What does that get you?

Comment: Hi Brian. thank you for your suggestion. but it is also not working. it always happens timeout error. there was no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add below line before execute line. It needs TLS12 as i figured out;

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```